# Unity3d VS Code configuration issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-framework-version

Error: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

1.I have done with reinstalling VSCODE
2.Done with changing .Net Framework from Unity Player Settings
Nothing Works, Still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue 2 days ago:

### How i solved it?

Install .netcore.

Then Go to "control panel" > "Programs" > "Programs and features" > "turn windows features on or off". You will see 2 .net frameworks including 4.7 that would be disabled.

[image]

Enable both frameworks. It may require download extra files so let it do so.[In my case, I had an old version of unity installed as well]

Let me know if it helps.